# SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI() not changing JFrames titlebar

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

**Environment:**

Using Netbeans 8.1

Oracle JDK 1.8

Win 10 pro

**Context:**

A GUI with a JCheckBoxMenuItem to change LookAndFeel(LAF) at runtime.

darkLAF=[JTattoo](http://www.jtattoo.net/)'s HiFi LAF

defaultLAF=Sun's Windows LAF(com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel)

**Problem:**

1. GUI launches(in EDT) with defaultLAF. User changes to darkLAF..the title bar should have changed..it doesn't.
2. When the user switches back to defaultLAF, the JMenuItems(File and Edit) show greyer backgrounds not the defaultLAF style.

**Screenshots:**

1. [The launched defaultLAF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwT1n.png)
2. [upon switching to darkLAF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F9vX.png)
3. [user switched back to defaultLAF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcE04.png)
4. [expected look for darkLAF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWAAF.png)

**Code:**

1. Inside the itemStateChangeListener for JCheckBoxMenuItem

   ```
   try{
      if (checkBox.isSelected())                                                                 
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel(darkLookAndFeel);
      else
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(defaultLookAndFeel);


   } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
      //handle err
   }

   //GUI is a class extending JFrame        
   SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
   //some JFileChooser
   SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(fc);

   pack();
   ```

**Catch:**

1. User shouldn't be asked to do a GUI restart.

Comment: The problem is, that the title bar can only be changed when the window is invisible. So you can try to make your window invisible, than set the new UI and make it visible after that.

Comment: using setVisible to hide the JFrame, then updating UI, then re instating the frame doesn't work @SergiyMedvynskyy

Comment: *"doesn't work"* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a little bit hard, but I've found a solution.

Steps you need to switch to the JTatto L&F

1. Dispose window
2. Set L&F
3. Set window style of root pane to `JRootPane.FRAME`
4. Update UI
5. Make Frame undecorated
6. Make Frame visible

Steps you need to switch back to Windows L&F

1. Dispose window
2. Set L&F
3. Update UI
4. Make Frame decorated
5. Make Frame visible

Here is the code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MinFrame extends JFrame {

    public MinFrame() {
        super("Minimal-Frame-Application");

        // setup menu
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menu.setMnemonic('F');
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        menuItem.setMnemonic('x');
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4, KeyEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        menu.add(menuItem);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        // setup widgets
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 4, 4, 4));
        JScrollPane westPanel = new JScrollPane(new JTree());
        JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane("text/plain", "Hello World");
        JScrollPane eastPanel = new JScrollPane(editor);
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, true, westPanel,eastPanel);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(148);
        contentPanel.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        AbstractButton winLF = new JButton("Windows");
        winLF.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    MinFrame.this.dispose();
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(MinFrame.this.getRootPane());

                    MinFrame.this.setUndecorated(false);
                    MinFrame.this.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        AbstractButton customLF = new JButton("JTatto");
        customLF.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    MinFrame.this.dispose();
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.smart.SmartLookAndFeel");
                    MinFrame.this.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(MinFrame.this.getRootPane());

                    MinFrame.this.setUndecorated(true);
                    MinFrame.this.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.add(winLF);
        buttons.add(customLF);
        contentPanel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setContentPane(contentPanel);

        // add listeners
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        // show application
        setLocation(32, 32);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);
    } // end CTor MinFrame

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // select Look and Feel
//            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.smart.SmartLookAndFeel");
            // start application
            new MinFrame();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // end main

}
```

Comment: many thanks for the solution...but switching back to defaultLAF still produces grayed out artifact in JMenuItems(see part 2 under "problem" in Question). Also could you explain the reasoning behind setting undecorated(true) even though we just set rootpane decorations to not none.

Comment: Another question-as upon launch,JRootPane decorations default to JRootPane.NONE and WindowsLookAndFeel.getSupportsWindowDecorations() returns false then why are there any decorations at all in the JFrame ?

Comment: @lineage 1) To solve the problem with your menu, you need to recreate it. I think it's a bug of `JTatto`. 2)  `setUndecorated` is required, because the window is created before the L&F was set. When you remove this line, you will get 2 title bars: native and from `JTatto`