# SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI() not changing JFrames titlebar for UNIX skin only

Tags: java, swing

Environment: Win 10 and Java SDK 12.01 (tested also on Java 8)

Problem similar to:

[SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI() not changing JFrames titlebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595444/swingutilities-updatecomponenttreeui-not-changing-jframes-titlebar)

but after I applied solution provided Unix Look and Feel change still doesn't work correctly (after change to Unix Look and feel title bar is still not updated or (after I apply setUndecorated() method - not visible at all).

Where I switch radiobutton to Windows skin - works as it should work:

[windows skin - correct case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZADG.jpg)

But when I switch radiobutton to Unix skin - all components are being refreshed fine EXCEPT title bar - it disapears:

[Unix skin - issue: title bar not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG7Gc.jpg)

Or, when I remove line:

```java
notepadWindow.setUndecorated(true);
```

from case UNIX in switch statement, title bar appears but not in Unix look and feel:

[Unix skin - title bar visible but from different look and feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3UE7.jpg)

Please find complete code (I tried to make it as simple as possible, complete working code):

```java
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    NotepadWindow notepadWindow = new NotepadWindow();
    }
}

class NotepadWindow extends JFrame {

    public JTextArea textArea;

    public NotepadWindow() {

        super("Notepad - no name");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        getRootPane().add(scroll);

        getRootPane().setJMenuBar(NotepadMenu.createMenuBar(this));

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(650, 550);
    }
}

class NotepadMenu {

    public static JMenuBar createMenuBar(NotepadWindow notepadWindow) {

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

        JMenu skin = new JMenu("Skin");
        JRadioButton winSkin = new JRadioButton("Windows Skin", true);
        JRadioButton unixSkin = new JRadioButton("Unix Skin", false);

        bg.add(winSkin);
        bg.add(unixSkin);

        winSkin.addActionListener(ie->{
                NotepadLookAndFeelManager.setLookAndFeel(NotepadLookAndFeelManager.LookAndFeelTypes.WINDOWS, notepadWindow);
        });

        unixSkin.addActionListener(ae->{
                NotepadLookAndFeelManager.setLookAndFeel(NotepadLookAndFeelManager.LookAndFeelTypes.UNIX, notepadWindow);
        });

        skin.add(winSkin);
        skin.add(unixSkin);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(skin);
        return menuBar;
    }
}

class NotepadLookAndFeelManager {

    public enum LookAndFeelTypes {
        WINDOWS,
        UNIX,
    }

    static void setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeelTypes lookAndFeelType, NotepadWindow notepadWindow) {

        try {
            switch (lookAndFeelType) {
                case WINDOWS:       //SWITCH TO WINDOWS WORKS FINE
                    notepadWindow.dispose();
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(notepadWindow.getRootPane());
                    notepadWindow.setUndecorated(false);
                    notepadWindow.setVisible(true);
                    break;

                case UNIX:      //SWITCH DOESN't WORK - TITLE BAR FROM DIFFERENT LAF
                    notepadWindow.dispose();
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
                    notepadWindow.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(notepadWindow.getRootPane());
                    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

                    notepadWindow.setUndecorated(true);
                    notepadWindow.setVisible(true);
                    break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"after I apply setUndecorated() method - not visible at all"* Wait, what? If the GUI is supposed to appear without the frame decorations it wouldn't matter. Also, why `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(notepadWindow.getRootPane());` and not `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(notepadWindow);`?

Comment: when I add the line:
notepadWindow.setUndecorated(true);
I have Unix skin without title bar. Wen remove the line, I get Unix skin with Windows title bar. 
I used: 
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(notepadWindow.getRootPane());
because it was a recommended way of update content in the answer I gave as a reference in my description. I also tried:
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(notepadWindow);
but no difference...

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I edited code to make it as simple as posible and isolated issue (now only two look and feels, windows working and Unix - the only one that doesn't work. I hope it's much more clearer now, I'd appreciate your help

Comment: OK yes, that is essentially a MRE / SSCCE. But I'm still a little confused. Is the app. being run on Windows or Unix / Linux? The aim is to allow the user to change the PLAF at run-time? From memory, there were some issues changing from ***Nimbus*** PLAF to other PLAFs, but I'd never heard of quirks with any others.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion: I run it as a desktop app in Win10 evironment. User is able to change skin on the fly - so after the app is started with default skin can switch to Unix skin. Problem is very similar to the following one here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595444/swingutilities-updatecomponenttreeui-not-changing-jframes-titlebar

And the solution provided by Sergiy Medvynskyy works for all skins except this Unix one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no better answer let me share my investigation output instead.

Unix ("motif") look and feel is not supported in macOS, so it's deprecated from Open JDK 13 and no longer recommended to use:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8218637